# Best way to Store and Count available stock (PostgreSQL)

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, database-design

I am not sure how to proceed with counting the stock and storing the stock in generated invoices.

**Live data: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/20ff4/4**

Table `articles` there the static product info is stored:

```
create table articles
(
    prod_article_pvt_uuid uuid default uuid_generate_v1() not null
        constraint proxies_pk
            primary key,
    prod_article_pub_uuid uuid default uuid_generate_v1mc(),
    prod_article_pub_id serial not null,
    t timestamp with time zone default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6),
    archived boolean default false,
    cat integer,
    prod_brand_id integer,
    barcode bigint,
    supplier_code varchar
);
```

This table opens a document, and defines the type of document:

```
create table documents
(
    sale_doc_pvt_uuid uuid default uuid_generate_v1() not null
        constraint documents_pk
            primary key,
    sale_doc_pub_uuid uuid default uuid_generate_v1mc(),
    sale_doc_alpha varchar,
    t timestamp with time zone default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6),
    archived boolean default false,
    sale_type_id integer not null,
    frozen boolean default false
);

create table types
(
    sale_type_id serial not null
        constraint types_pk
            primary key,
    name varchar,
    draft boolean default false
);
```

Where each artricle is added as an item of the document:

```
create table items
(
    sale_unit_pvt_uuid uuid default uuid_generate_v1() not null
        constraint units_pk
            primary key,
    sale_unit_pub_uuid uuid default uuid_generate_v1mc(),
    t timestamp with time zone default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6),
    archived boolean default false,
    sale_doc_pvt_uuid uuid not null,
    prod_article_pvt_uuid uuid not null,
    quantity numeric(16,6) not null
);
```

These are the available products in the warehouse:

```
create table products
(
    whse_prod_pvt_uuid uuid default uuid_generate_v1() not null,
    whse_prod_pub_uuid uuid default uuid_generate_v1mc(),
    t_created timestamp with time zone default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6),
    prod_article_pvt_uuid uuid not null,
    quantity numeric(16,6) default 1,
    global_ctry_id integer
);
```

---

I am trying to query this like so:

```
SELECT
     (sum(products.quantity) - COALESCE(_items.quantity, 0)) as quantity
     ,articles.prod_article_pub_id as article

 FROM products

 LEFT JOIN articles ON products.prod_article_pvt_uuid = articles.prod_article_pvt_uuid

 LEFT JOIN (
     SELECT DISTINCT ON (items.prod_article_pvt_uuid)
         items.prod_article_pvt_uuid
         ,items.sale_doc_pvt_uuid
         ,sum(items.quantity) as quantity
     FROM items
     LEFT JOIN documents ON items.sale_doc_pvt_uuid = documents.sale_doc_pvt_uuid
     LEFT JOIN types ON documents.sale_type_id = types.sale_type_id
     WHERE
         items.archived = false
     AND documents.archived = false
     AND types.draft = false
     GROUP BY
         items.prod_article_pvt_uuid
         ,items.sale_doc_pvt_uuid
 ) AS _items ON _items.prod_article_pvt_uuid = products.prod_article_pvt_uuid


 GROUP BY
     articles.prod_article_pub_id
     ,_items.quantity

 ORDER BY
     article ASC,
     quantity DESC
```

It does give me the desired result. But I am wondering if this is the correct way at going about it, cause it looks like it might struggle with millions of rows.

Basically each time I need to display the quantity available in stock I have to count every single document ever generated.

Is this a good idea?

Will it be a performance bottle neck with millions of rows?

Comment: I can't tell about PostgreSQL options, but in our MS SQL we have done that in two ways. At first, we used triggers to automatically update stock balance, this sometimes created deadlocks and other synchronizaton problems. Now we are using materialized views - generally much better; millions of rows are not problem with either case. Simple querying aggregates over millions of rows gets slow, like you already guessed.

Comment: @Arvo The thing is I don't want to (and don't think I should) change the original quantity when the product was acquired in table `products`. Therefore I am subtracting all the products that were sold. And returning the quantity. This allows me to track a sale all the way to the origin. But I am worried about the performance when fetching the stock availability like this.

Comment: Likely I forgot to tell that for trigger based solution we were using separate table for current stock balance - of course original quantities should remain intact.

Comment: @Arvo Yeah I got that. However I am worried that we might sell something we don't have in stock with this approach. What was your solution for this? About the materialized view, how often do you update it/how long does it take to update the entire inventory (I'm guessing)?

Comment: Our trigger made stock balance negative in that case, [not] allowing to sell such items was solved at client side (some customers require negative balances as well). Materialized views (at least on MS SQL) are updating automatically, I have no performance numbers about updating row data, but materialized views are for sure faster than triggers. Like I said, I have no knowledge about PostgreSQL - does it include possibility to create materialized (indexed) views and what kind of query options are allowed there and what not; these were just ideas to investigate.

Comment: @Arvo I was only curious how you handled it in MS SQL. The trigger solution is not very appealing to me for sure. PSQL does have materialized views, I've never used it so I'll be exploring for sure.